# Selenium IDE find Elements by Icons

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to figure out which Selenium command I should use when I try to locate a button **with no value in** and presented with an icon.

This button can change his location, i have already tried using

```
//div[@id='mainGridContainer']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td/button[2]
```

This works, but only for that specific line. The problem is that the button can change  location from line to line.

Here is the relevant HTML:

```
<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" title="Edit details" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
  <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"> </span>
  <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
</button>
```

Comment: Please show the relevant html containing the button.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='mainGridContainer']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/button[2]</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>

Comment: That's not what he meant OP. He meant the actual HTML, not the selenium IDE script source

Comment: Doesn't look like a real html code. Where is your button tag defined?

Comment: I hope that is better now, Sorry:

<button class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-icon-only" title="Edit details" 
role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-pencil">
</span><span class="ui-button-text"></span></button>

Answer (score 1):

Using the `title` attribute, you can cleanly select this element using CSS.

```
css=button[title='Edit details']
```

No need using Xpath, or even using the parent-child hierarchy.

Comment: The Command supposed to be 'click', right?
it is excuting fine but not opening the window it should open, by clicking it.

Comment: it all depends on what is receiving the click.  It's most likely the button, so click this element, yes

Comment: Unfortunally, it is not opening the window it is supposed to, any other idea?

Comment: Is there more than one element on the page with the title of 'Edit details'?

Comment: Yes, there are few different buttons.

Comment: then you need to match something else for specificity.  What's the element that is wrapping that button?  Is there a form?  Then we can do `css=form#someForm button[title='Edit details']`